# C# automatic login to gmail/hotmail via web browser

Tags: c#, api, outlook, gmail, gmail-api

I`m trying to do something like LassPass, but as a desktop application. I use VS 2013, C# and Windows Forms.

I have my user email and password for gmail or outlook and I want to click a button in my desktop program to open my local default browser ie., Chrome/Firefox with appropriate link. I want to be automatic login in service(gmail/outlook). I want to ask if I have to use appropriate API or only some kind of link (https://mail.google.com/login="userlogin",password="userpassword") will be good.

I see a gmail API, there is how to send a mail, but i cannot find how to log into service.

Are in Gmail or Outlook API functions which can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [Selenium](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium)

once you have it setup you can do something like

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium;

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.gmail.com/");
        IWebElement query = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Email"));
        query.SendKeys("my.email@gmail.com");
        query = driver.FindElement(By.Id("next"));
        query.Click();
        // now you just have to do the same for the password page

        driver.Quit();
    }
}
```

You may find these links helpful:

- http://james-prescott.com/2014/02/01/tutorial-setting-up-selenium-webdriver-visual-studio/
- http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#the-5-minute-getting-started-guide

Comment: Is using Selenium 100 safe?

Comment: what do you mean by "safe"?

Comment: This is definitely helpful, but I'm getting "NoSuchElementException was unhandled" when trying to get the password. Doing it exactly the same way as with the username (and I've got the right Id: `Passwd`), but still no luck. Tried get the element by name instead of id and still the same error. Is there something that prevents selenium from getting a password field (for security reasons)?

Comment: Figured it out. For anyone that has this issue in the future, you need to wait until the element is visible: `driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));`

Answer (score 0):

For Gmail you can use below code for authentication

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Imap client = new Imap();
// connect to server
client.Connect("imap.gmail.com", 993, SslMode.Implicit);
// authenticate
client.Login("username", "password");

}
```